# How can i remove specific element in a vector inside a list using index number in R programming

Tags: r

I will try explaining it python where it would be helpful if some let me know how to do it in R programming

**INPUT:**
I have a dict with list of values

```
my_dict = {
   data_point1:[
     {
       "sample1": "a"
     },
     {
       "sample2": "b"
     }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to remove sample1 obj inside data_points list, I can do this easily in python using pop provided with index number as 0

**Expected_output:**

```
my_dict = {
   data_point1:[
     {
       "sample2": "b"
     }
  ]
}
```

**Please Note** I have to remove elements inside list using index numbers only since its dynamically fetched n a forloop. It would be great if somebody helps me to implement this logic in R programming Thanks in advance!!!!

**My Tries in R:**

- mydict[[data_point]][1] <- NULL
- mydict[[data_point]] <- mydict[[data_point]][-1]

**R data structure of input:**

```
list(data_point = list("sample1" = c(1000,2), "sample2"= c(200,300)))
```

Here in need to remove the 1000 from sample1 element using index number

**Expected output in R data structure:**

```
list(data_point = list("sample1" = c(2), "sample2"= c(200,300)))
```

Comment: No its just a json which is getting converted to R understandable list format, its just a list of elements

Comment: i will edit it now sorry

Comment: Does `mydict$data_point$sample1 <- NULL` work for you

Comment: or even `mydict[['data_point']][['sample1']] <- NULL`

Comment: ya it will work but i want to remove it using index number

Comment: `mydict[["data_point"]] <- mydict[["data_point"]][-1]` or `mydict$data_point <- mydict$data_point[-1]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to assign the inner list element to `NULL`, extract the element with either `$` or `[[`

```
mydict$datapoint$sample1 <- NULL
```

-output

```
> mydict
$data_point
$data_point$sample2
[1] "2"
> dput(mydict)
list(data_point = list(sample2 = "2"))
```

---

For the updated case, assign by taking the second element for the 'sample1'

```
mydict2$data_point$sample1 <- mydict2$data_point$sample1[2]
> dput(mydict2)
list(data_point = list(sample1 = 2, sample2 = c(200, 300)))
```

---

Or by index

```
mydict2$data_point$sample1 <- mydict2$data_point$sample1[-1]
> mydict2
$data_point
$data_point$sample1
[1] 2

$data_point$sample2
[1] 200 300
```

---

If we want to remove all 1st elements from the 'data_point', loop

```
mydict2$data_point <- lapply(mydict2$data_point, `[`, -1)
> mydict2
$data_point
$data_point$sample1
[1] 2

$data_point$sample2
[1] 300
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
 for(i in seq_along(mydict2$data_point)) 
      mydict2$data_point[[i]] <- mydict2$data_point[[i]][-1]
> mydict2
$data_point
$data_point$sample1
[1] 2

$data_point$sample2
[1] 300
```

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look when u have time thanks

Comment: @Aks you need `mydict2$data_point$sample1 <- mydict2$data_point$sample1[2]`

Comment: @Aks The `c(2)` part is simply `2` i.e. by default when it is a single element, it drops those `c()`, but it is still a vector

Comment: The logic am trying to implement is I need to remove a specific index and keep the rest because I will not be knowing how many elements present in it since index number is a indentifier in my case

Comment: @AkshayGeedan I thought the OP is Aks

Comment: @AkshayGeedan your comment is not clear.  You said specific index.  In the new update, what is your specific index i.e. when you have 1000 and 2 in sample1, what does 2 indicate.  Does it say to keep the 2nd element, then why is sample2 values not have any index i.e. 200 and 300

Comment: It can be a dynamic integer number which will specify the index of the element to be removed in sample1

Comment: @AkshayGeedan that part i understand, but how do we know which one is index and which one is not i.e. in `sample2` you have two vvalues 200 and 300 and thus it is not an index?

Comment: @AkshayGeedan with the index I assume `mydict2$data_point$sample1 <- mydict2$data_point$sample1[-1]` and it gives the same output as expected

Comment: 200 and 300 are values present in 1st and second index of sample2 where I need to remove 200 using index number

Comment: @AkshayGeedan but your expected shows `list(data_point = list("sample1" = c(2), "sample2"= c(200,300)))`

Comment: I tried ur last solution but it didn't work out I was getting a index out of bounds error

Comment: Just gave an example

Comment: @AkshayGeedan if you have already done the assignment earlier on the same object, it will be having length shortage.  I assume that you are doing this on the orignal object

Comment: @AkshayGeedan can you update your post with exact output you needed as it is not clear bbased on your descrption

Comment: I tried doing it in a copy of that list and perform my removal operations and then reassigning to the original object is what I tried

Comment: @AkshayGeedan anyway, I get the same output as the one I updated earlier. updated

Comment: @AkshayGeedan let me clarify.  are you trying to remove both 1000 and 200 automatically?

Comment: It's okay thanks for your valuable efforts I will try finding a solution

Comment: Yes am trying to remove it automatically

Comment: @AkshayGeedan i updated.  hope it works now

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this using `purrr`.

```r
library(purrr)
my_list <- list(data_point = list("sample1" = c(1000,2), "sample2"= c(200,300)))

remove_value <- function(x, value) x[!x == value]
map_depth(my_list, 2, remove_value, value = 1000)
```

```r
$data_point
$data_point$sample1
[1] 2

$data_point$sample2
[1] 200 300
```

Or to remove a specific index...

```r
remove_index <- function(x, index) x[-index]
map_depth(my_list, 2, remove_index, index = 1)
```